# Viertelgeviertstrich/hyphen with UnifrakturMaguntia and XeLatex

Tags: xetex

I'm trying to get Fraktur-letters to work in Texstudio. It's working mostly, but not the "Viertelgeviertstrich"/`-` which should become a short `=`.

https://ibb.co/Wtv363S
The top of the picture shows how the 3 hyphen types should look like. Then in the middle are two examples how they should look like in text, one in the middle and one at the end.
But at the bottom is the result I get, no errors in the console.

Not even working in this simple document:

```
% !TeX program = xelatex
\documentclass{minimal}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\defaultfontfeatures{Ligatures=TeX}
\setmainfont{UnifrakturMaguntia19}
\begin{document}
H-Milch
i-Punkt
100-prozentig
\end{document}
```

log:

```
This is XeTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-0.999992 (MiKTeX 20.11) (preloaded format=xelatex 2020.11.27)  27 NOV 2020 21:13
entering extended mode
**./document.tex
(document.tex
LaTeX2e <2020-10-01> patch level 2
L3 programming layer <2020-10-27> xparse <2020-03-03>
(C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/latex/base\minimal.cls
Document Class: minimal 2001/05/25 Standard LaTeX minimal class
) (C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/latex/fontspec\fontspec.sty
(C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/latex/l3packages/xparse\xparse
.sty (C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/latex/l3kernel\expl3.sty
Package: expl3 2020-10-27 L3 programming layer (loader) 

(C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/latex/l3backend\l3backend-xete
x.def
File: l3backend-xetex.def 2020-09-24 L3 backend support: XeTeX
\g__graphics_track_int=\count171
\l__pdf_internal_box=\box47
\g__pdf_backend_object_int=\count172
\g__pdf_backend_annotation_int=\count173
))
Package: xparse 2020-10-27 L3 Experimental document command parser

(C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/latex/l3packages/xparse\xparse
-generic.tex))
Package: fontspec 2020/02/21 v2.7i Font selection for XeLaTeX and LuaLaTeX

(C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/latex/fontspec\fontspec-xetex.
sty
Package: fontspec-xetex 2020/02/21 v2.7i Font selection for XeLaTeX and LuaLaTe
X
\l__fontspec_script_int=\count174
\l__fontspec_language_int=\count175
\l__fontspec_strnum_int=\count176
\l__fontspec_tmp_int=\count177
\l__fontspec_tmpa_int=\count178
\l__fontspec_tmpb_int=\count179
\l__fontspec_tmpc_int=\count180
\l__fontspec_em_int=\count181
\l__fontspec_emdef_int=\count182
\l__fontspec_strong_int=\count183
\l__fontspec_strongdef_int=\count184
\l__fontspec_tmpa_dim=\dimen138
\l__fontspec_tmpb_dim=\dimen139
\l__fontspec_tmpc_dim=\dimen140
 (C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/latex/base\fontenc.sty
Package: fontenc 2020/08/10 v2.0s Standard LaTeX package
)
(C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/latex/fontspec\fontspec.cfg)))

Package fontspec Info: Could not resolve font "UnifrakturMaguntia19/BI" (it
(fontspec)             probably doesn't exist).


Package fontspec Info: Could not resolve font "UnifrakturMaguntia19/B" (it
(fontspec)             probably doesn't exist).


Package fontspec Info: Could not resolve font "UnifrakturMaguntia19/I" (it
(fontspec)             probably doesn't exist).


Package fontspec Info: Font family 'UnifrakturMaguntia19(0)' created for font
(fontspec)             'UnifrakturMaguntia19' with options
(fontspec)             [Ligatures=TeX,Ligatures=TeX].
(fontspec)              
(fontspec)              This font family consists of the following NFSS
(fontspec)             series/shapes:
(fontspec)              
(fontspec)             - 'normal' (m/n) with NFSS spec.:
(fontspec)             <->"UnifrakturMaguntia19/OT:script=latn;language=dflt;ma
pping=tex-text;"
(fontspec)             - 'small caps'  (m/sc) with NFSS spec.: 

(document.aux)
\openout1 = `document.aux'.

LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OML/cmm/m/it on input line 6.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 6.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OMS/cmsy/m/n on input line 6.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 6.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OT1/cmr/m/n on input line 6.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 6.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for T1/cmr/m/n on input line 6.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 6.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for TS1/cmr/m/n on input line 6.
LaTeX Font Info:    Trying to load font information for TS1+cmr on input line 6
.

(C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/latex/base\ts1cmr.fd
File: ts1cmr.fd 2019/12/16 v2.5j Standard LaTeX font definitions
)
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 6.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for TU/lmr/m/n on input line 6.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 6.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OMX/cmex/m/n on input line 6.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 6.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for U/cmr/m/n on input line 6.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 6.

Package fontspec Info: Adjusting the maths setup (use [no-math] to avoid
(fontspec)             this).

\symlegacymaths=\mathgroup4
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting symbol font `legacymaths' in version `bold'
(Font)                  OT1/cmr/m/n --> OT1/cmr/bx/n on input line 6.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring math accent \acute on input line 6.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring math accent \grave on input line 6.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring math accent \ddot on input line 6.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring math accent \tilde on input line 6.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring math accent \bar on input line 6.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring math accent \breve on input line 6.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring math accent \check on input line 6.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring math accent \hat on input line 6.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring math accent \dot on input line 6.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring math accent \mathring on input line 6.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring math symbol \colon on input line 6.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring math symbol \Gamma on input line 6.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring math symbol \Delta on input line 6.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring math symbol \Theta on input line 6.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring math symbol \Lambda on input line 6.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring math symbol \Xi on input line 6.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring math symbol \Pi on input line 6.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring math symbol \Sigma on input line 6.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring math symbol \Upsilon on input line 6.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring math symbol \Phi on input line 6.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring math symbol \Psi on input line 6.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring math symbol \Omega on input line 6.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring math symbol \mathdollar on input line 6.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring symbol font `operators' on input line 6.
LaTeX Font Info:    Encoding `OT1' has changed to `TU' for symbol font
(Font)              `operators' in the math version `normal' on input line 6.
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting symbol font `operators' in version `normal'
(Font)                  OT1/cmr/m/n --> TU/UnifrakturMaguntia19(0)/m/n on input
 line 6.
LaTeX Font Info:    Encoding `OT1' has changed to `TU' for symbol font
(Font)              `operators' in the math version `bold' on input line 6.
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting symbol font `operators' in version `bold'
(Font)                  OT1/cmr/bx/n --> TU/UnifrakturMaguntia19(0)/m/n on inpu
t line 6.
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting symbol font `operators' in version `normal'
(Font)                  TU/UnifrakturMaguntia19(0)/m/n --> TU/UnifrakturMagunti
a19(0)/m/n on input line 6.
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting math alphabet `\mathit' in version `normal'
(Font)                  OT1/cmr/m/it --> TU/UnifrakturMaguntia19(0)/m/it on inp
ut line 6.
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting math alphabet `\mathbf' in version `normal'
(Font)                  OT1/cmr/bx/n --> TU/UnifrakturMaguntia19(0)/b/n on inpu
t line 6.
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting math alphabet `\mathsf' in version `normal'
(Font)                  OT1/cmss/m/n --> TU/lmss/m/n on input line 6.
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting math alphabet `\mathtt' in version `normal'
(Font)                  OT1/cmtt/m/n --> TU/lmtt/m/n on input line 6.
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting symbol font `operators' in version `bold'
(Font)                  TU/UnifrakturMaguntia19(0)/m/n --> TU/UnifrakturMagunti
a19(0)/b/n on input line 6.
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting math alphabet `\mathit' in version `bold'
(Font)                  OT1/cmr/bx/it --> TU/UnifrakturMaguntia19(0)/b/it on in
put line 6.
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting math alphabet `\mathsf' in version `bold'
(Font)                  OT1/cmss/bx/n --> TU/lmss/b/n on input line 6.
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting math alphabet `\mathtt' in version `bold'
(Font)                  OT1/cmtt/m/n --> TU/lmtt/b/n on input line 6.
Missing character: There is no - in font UnifrakturMaguntia19/OT:script=latn;la
nguage=dflt;mapping=tex-text;!
Missing character: There is no - in font UnifrakturMaguntia19/OT:script=latn;la
nguage=dflt;mapping=tex-text;!
Missing character: There is no - in font UnifrakturMaguntia19/OT:script=latn;la
nguage=dflt;mapping=tex-text;!
 [1]
(document.aux) ) 
Here is how much of TeX's memory you used:
 2582 strings out of 414107
 90154 string characters out of 2880832
 402076 words of memory out of 3000000
 22042 multiletter control sequences out of 15000+200000
 535144 words of font info for 36 fonts, out of 3000000 for 9000
 14 hyphenation exceptions out of 8191
 78i,4n,86p,267b,224s stack positions out of 5000i,500n,10000p,200000b,50000s

Output written on document.pdf (1 page).
```

Answer (score 4):

According to your log, you’re using a version of the font that somehow does not contain the hyphen-minus character.

When I compile with the [full version of the font](http://unifraktur.sourceforge.net/maguntia.html) and set the same options as for UnifrakturMaguntia19, per the documentation, it works for me, with double hyphens:

```
% !TeX program = xelatex
\documentclass{minimal}
\tracinglostchars=2
\usepackage{fontspec}
\defaultfontfeatures{Ligatures=TeX}
\setmainfont{UnifrakturMaguntia.ttf}[
  Ligatures={Common,Historic},
  CharacterVariant={11,13,14,19},
  Numbers=Lining] % 19th-century options.

\begin{document}
H-Milch
i-Punkt
100-prozentig
\end{document}
```

This should work the way the font you loaded is supposed to, and not be broken.  (The numbered variants are really for applications where an author is not able to individually select OpenType features.)

You might also see if there’s a more recent version of `UnifrakturMaguntia19.ttf` that fixes this.

Answer (score 4):

You shouldn't use the `19` variant, but the standard font.

I downloaded the fonts from SourceForge and unzipped the archive. In the top-level directory I prepared the file

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{UnifrakturMaguntia}[Path=./,Extension=.ttf]
\newfontfamily{\nineteen}{UnifrakturMaguntia19}[Path=./switched-on_features/,Extension=.ttf]
\begin{document}
H-Milch
i-Punkt
100-prozentig

\nineteen
H-Milch
i-Punkt
100-prozentig
\end{document}
```

and I got

[image]

The fonts in the `switched-on_features` directory have enabled features according to the following table

[image]

You can enable each feature by passing options to `\setmainfont`. For instance, in order to enable `ss01` you can do

```
\setmainfont{UnifrakturMaguntia}[
  Path=./, % adjust the path or remove this if the font is installed system-wide
  Extension=.ttf, % remove if the font is installed system-wide
  StylisticSet=1,
]
```

With `StylisticSet={1,2}` you enable both `ss01` and `ss02`.

For the `cv` variants, you can add options such as

```
CharacterVariant={11,14}
```

to enable both `cv11` and `cv14`. For `lnum` the option is `Numbers=Lining`, for `hlig` it is `Ligatures={TeX,Historical}` (you want to keep also the TeX-style ligatures).